# How to dynamically generate a table based off of metadata that isn't a direct 1-to-1 mapping

Tags: javascript

I'm building yet-another-booking web app and I've run into a problem that my limited javascript knowledge can't sort out in a simple way.

I have 2 functions that are returning relevant data.  For the selected day, one function returns the opening and closing hours.  A second function returns metadata about individual events that have been booked previously on that day.

Based on the above 2 functions, I want to render a time picker in a table so that, separated by hour, where each hour is displayed as either already booked (with some metadata from the above functions) or as available and can be clicked to book time.

I had a look at knockout.js, but it doesn't feel like quite the right fit since the models don't map to the view so directly and I want to render a clickable table row based on that data.

My question is, what is the standard method for dynamically generating this kind of table based off of some metadata accessible through ajax calls?  How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should: Show example input, show example of expected output, and consider including what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no "standard" method, it all depends on what libraries and approach you want to use.

Personally I'd try to consolidate the two functions into one AJAX call (saves having to handle synchronicity issues with the return times of 2 calls).

For a pure JavaScript solution, I'd do something like add the table when the AJAX call returns, then loop through the hourly times and generate the rows based on the AJAX data.

```
// setup ajax request.....
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
        var timeTable = document.createElement('div');

        for (var i = openTime; i < closingTime; i++) {
            var row = document.createElement('div');
            if (
                // check to see if this hour has a booking
            ) {
                // generate a 'booked' row
            } else {
                // generate a 'free' row
            }
            timeTable.appendChild(row);
        }

        // place table in the correct place in the document
    }
}
```

if you want to be changing the table dynamically as the user selects different days then you just need to empty the old div.

Considering this isn't really tabulated data, I'd steer away from using table tags.